# How to solve Kakurasu Puzzle in an efficient time?

Tags: algorithm, puzzle

I'm trying to write a code in Java to find a solution of an instance of a Kakurasu puzzle in an efficient time. I was thinking about using dynamic programming but couldn't figure out how to do that.

Comment: Do you mean [this](http://translate.google.com/translate?u=https%3A//www.janko.at/Raetsel/Kakurasu/index.htm&langpair=auto|en&tbb=1&ie=UTF-8) kind of puzzle? Please include a reference on the exact rules of the puzzle, and ideally an example.

Comment: The rules are: the numbers on the top are the sum of black square weight specified with the numbers on the right. The numbers on the left border are the sum of black square weight specified by the numbers at bottom.

Comment: @Codor Yes, I meant that kind of puzzle. Thank you.

Comment: This is a system of 'boolean linear equations,' a subset of Diophantine (integer) linear equations. For an nxn grid, the rows and columns form 2n equations, with the cells forming n^2 boolean variables.

Answer (score 3):

I describe here the algorithm to find the solutions of a kakurasu. A solver implementation in the Go programming language can be found [here](https://github.com/chmike/kakurasu).

A kakurasu is an *n* rows by *m* colums grid puzzle. The goal of the puzzle is to determine the black or white color of all cells by using the sums of weight of black cells in all rows and columns. The weight is a number from 1 to n.

The image bellow shows a solved kakurasu. The numbers on the top and left sides are the row and column weights. The numbers on the right and at the bottom are the sums of weights of black cells.

[image: Solved kakurasu example]

Each sum has a limited set of possible weight combinations. From this set of possible solutions we can deduce that some cells must be white and others must be black because they are respectively white or black in all solutions. The image below illustrate the deduction we can make from the sum 9. A cell color is grey when it’s color is left unknown by the deduction.

[image: deduction example]

Once we deduced the color of a cell, we can prune solutions with an incompatible color from the row or column containing the cell. By repeating the deduction and pruning operations, we can deduce the color of the grid cells. This deduction process ends when the color of all cells has been determined, or when no new deductions can be made. In the later case we are left with cells of unknown color. This means that there are multiple solutions where the cells of unknown color are black and white.

To find the different solutions, we solve by assign the color white to a cell of unknown color, and again by assigning the color black to that cell. This can be repeated as needed until the color of all cells has been determined for all solutions.